# AAD Graph API - check if user must change password

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I create new user in Azure Active Directory with flag "ForcePasswordChange" set to true.
When I try to login to AAD using API an error "Invalid username or password" occur.
How can I check (using Graph API) if user must change password before login?

If I use Microsoft AAD authentication window after login I'm redirected to page where I have to change my password, but in our company we cannot use that window, so we need to implement own login window.

Code I use to login:

```
string clientId = "client guid";
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential("username", "password");
var result = authContext.AcquireToken("resource", clientId, uc);
```

Thanks

Comment: Which authentication flow are you using to authenticate the user?

Comment: What do you mean by authentication flow?

Comment: The code sample answers the question. You're using the ["Resource Owner Password Credentials" flow of OAuth 2.0](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3). (With ADAL, this happens when you pass a UserCredential.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the error response when the user is required to change their password, and the error response when the password is incorrect is the same. There is also no method currently to query Graph API to identify if a given user is required to change their password.